# PHP get http url and return https url

Tags: php, ssl, https, proxy

I am not really sure how to do this, I have an URL like this http://turgw.t4w.com.br/_teste/fornecedor/geopopup.aspx?HotelID=142498, wich I need to get the content, and return it to a website that uses ssl. The URL above does not suport ssl, so the browser is bloking it and I am wondering if I could get the content with php and use my server as a proxy and return a new url from my domain and ssl encrypted. Anyone can help? Thank You!

Comment: Sure, you can use cURL to scrape it and then serve it on your SSL server, but you'll need to replace your `http://` link in that page with `https://`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out `readfile`: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.readfile.php

You could use it like this:

```
readfile('http://turgw.t4w.com.br/_teste/fornecedor/geopopup.aspx?HotelID=142498');
```

That should be all you need to do what you specified.